# User input of a number to list of sequencial following numbers to 0

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm pretty new to python/coding in general. I'm trying to take *user input* which I will get to later and turn it into a *list* from *0 - x*. I have this :

```
x=[ ]
for i in range (args[0]+1):
    x = i
return x
print (main(5))
```

The *x= i* part is what I can't figure out right now. Each attempt I've done gives me *IndexError: tuple index out of range*

Comment: Specifically, what type of user input? Is it space separated int? Please give sample input and output. Also, in python, getting user input is through the function *anyvar = input()* which returns your input to *anyvar*.

Comment: It would just be one integer. Right now to build the code I am just using *5* in place of `int(input(prompt)) ` so that I don't have to keep inputting a number

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have saved your input to *i*, i.e.

```
i = input()
```

you can make a list by passing it through:

```
x = [num for num in range(int(i)+1)]
```

for example, if i=5, this will make:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: You're Welcome. =3

Answer (score 0):

This works.

Replace `target=10` with your user input.

Are you trying to code it in one line for brevity or for a particular requirement?

```
target = 10
x = [0]
while x[-1] < target:
    x.append(x[-1]+1)
print(x)
```

Comment: Seraph's is better than mine. :-)

Comment: It was only 1 line because I couldn't figure out how to separate the lines through the app

Comment: Is target built in to python or just a variable

Comment: `target` is my variable name.